# In R: Extract similar trajectory patterns from a data table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table that contains several patterns for going from `a` to `c`. These patterns are assigned to different expeditions. I want to extract similar patterns for the different `expedition_id`.

```
dt<- data.table(departure = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a','d','a', 'b'), arrival = 
       c('a','a','b','c','d','c','b','c'), expedition_id = c(1,2,1,1,3,3,2,2))


 >dt          
departure      arrival    expedition_id
   a              a            1
   a              a            2
   a              b            1
   b              c            1
   a              d            3
   d              c            3
   a              b            2
   b              c            2
```

The results that I am trying to get look like different data tables for each unique pattern.

```
>dt1

departure       arrival         expedition_list
   a                a                1,2
   a                b                1,2
   b                c                1,2

>dt2

departure       arrival         expedition_list
   a                d                3
   d                c                3
```

I'd appreciate your help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- dt[, .(expedition_list = toString(expedition_id)), by = .(departure, arrival)]
dt_list <- split(dt, dt$expedition_list)

list2env(
  setNames(
    dt_list,
    paste0('dt', 1:length(dt_list))
  ),
  .GlobalEnv
)
```

Output:

```
dt1

   departure arrival expedition_list
1:         a       a            1, 2
2:         a       b            1, 2
3:         b       c            1, 2

dt2

   departure arrival expedition_list
1:         a       d               3
2:         d       c               3
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for `data.table` but for others this `dplyr` version might also be helpful:

```
dt %>%
    group_by(departure, arrival) %>%
    summarise(expedition_list = paste(expedition_id, collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not give me the final results. Besides that, it does not give back the similar patterns.